# How to highlight by gradient specific range of values from the same field in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, values

There is a field about alcohol consumption by country with 10 max. and 10 min. values (picture 1).
Need to choose only 10 max. values and create a gradient map. Seems its needs to be some expression, but I don't know what exactly. Trying simple   `"alco_cons"  >= '10'` but its not I'm looking for (picture 2). I need to grade only 10 max values. Example of what it needs to look like in picture 3.

[image: picture 1]

[image: picture 2]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

An easy way is to duplicate the layer, set a filter on the layer to only show top 10 regions. Symbolize this with a Graduated symbology, place it on top of the unfiltered layer

[image]

Comment: Well, when I try to graduate it with an expression  "alco_cons"  > '10'  it returns only '0', '1' and 'other' instead of 10 unique values

Comment: Do you have a string field?

Comment: Yes, but I tried with real field

Comment: You should use any expression to graduate. The expression is used to filter the layer (right-click Filter)

Comment: Yes, but it filtered to only 3 conditions: '0', '1' and 'other', while I need 10 unique

Comment: `"alco_cons" > 10` is correct, `"alco_cons" > '10' `  is incorrect

Comment: Even "alco_cons" > 10 still returns the same '0', '1' and 'other' values, not 10 unique

Comment: You shouldnt use a string field.